# aws-amplify-react . Authenticator Component - Signout Button

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Following

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#using-the-authenticator-component-directly

```
import { Authenticator} from 'aws-amplify-react'
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import aws_exports from './aws_exports';


Amplify.configure(aws_exports);


const AppWithAuth = () => (
    <Authenticator>
            <App/>
    </Authenticator>
)

export default AppWithAuth
```

I am trying to use the Authenicator component directly.
How do I display a signout button once I am logged in.

Tried following 
https://github.com/richardzcode/Journal-AWS-Amplify-Tutorial/tree/master/step-02#sign-out-button

```
import { Authenticator , SignOut} from 'aws-amplify-react'

const AppWithAuth = () => (
    <Authenticator>
        <SignOut />
            <App/>
    </Authenticator>
)
```

But Signout button is still not visible

Answer (score 9):

This will not use the SignOut Component, but is an alternative way of loggin out.You will need to create your own signOut Button.

This is taken from https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication
So in Navbar or where ever you want to create your signOut button, you can add:

```
  signOut = () => {
    Auth.signOut()
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  // Then in your render method.
  <button onClick={this.signOut} className="signOutButton">SignOut</button>
```

It requires that you wrapp your App export using "withAuthenticator"

so f.x. In your App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withAuthenticator } from "aws-amplify-react";
class App extends Component {
     ...
}
export default withAuthenticator(App, false);
```

false here means no sigOut button. If you try it using true you get the Default signOut button.

After this, you can style the button anyway you like.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It could be because `SignOut` button is outside `App`. It probably is rendered but just not visible because of CSS layout.

Note in the tutorial the `SignOut` button is on `Navigator` which is inside `App`.

BTW you don't necessarily need to wrap `SignOut` button inside `Authenticator`. Put it on anywhere, then show / hide base on `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` result.

Comment: What is the most basic css to make it visible?

Comment: I was just guessing. Using web browser's "inspect" tool may find the dom element.

Another possible reason is that your are not in `signedIn` status yet. Normally after sign in there is a 'confirm sign in' status which user need to give confirmation code received from SMS. Do you want to check that also?. In your code also `import { Logger } from 'aws-amplify'` then `Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'` may give you more information in browser console.

Comment: Auth.signOut() works well. Otherwise, we end up passing around signOut function / component around from Authenticator.